# 400 (Bad Request) error + angular

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I am receiving a 400 (Bad Request) error  in my angular application.

Submitting user details customerLoginController.js:10
POST `http://localhost:8080/login` 400 (Bad Request) angular.min.js:77
Error in upload

What is happening at the moment is that I can see my console.logs going through but the data is not passing through for the customer username and password.

my code here in the form and then in my controller:

```
<div class="loginForm" ng-controller="customerLoginController">
    <form method="POST">
        Username: <br /> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your username" ng-model="customer.username" /><br /><br />

        Password: <br /> 
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" ng-model="customer.password" />

        <span class="promptDetails" ng-click="getUserCredentials()"><a ui-sref="#" class="fetchLogDetails">Forgot login details</a></span>
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="loginUser" value="Login" ng-click="login(customer)" />
    </form>
</div><!-- End login form -->
```

My controller for the form

```
angular
.module('customerProfile')
.controller('customerLoginController', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.customer = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    },

    $scope.login = function(customer) {
        console.log("Submitting user details");
            $http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', customer)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(msg.data);
            })
            .error(function() {
                console.log("Error in upload");
            })


    };

})
```

Comment: how you are handling the login on serverside? Please post the serverside login handler for us to debug.